# Get used time for planning path

Tags: ros, python, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Is there a python command of the moveit_commander lib to get the used (!) planning time for the last planning? Perhaps the time is also stored in the result of the "plan" command?

At the moment I have identified the following information in the results:

```
plan = self.move_group.plan()
# plan[0] == True if planning was successfull
# plan[1] <- trajectory
```

Is there an overview of the structure of the "plan" result?
Thanks in advance!

nico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394226/get-used-time-for-planning-path/) by [nicob](https://answers.ros.org/users/85320/nicob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2022-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution by myself after some study of the planning results array...

It is much more simple as I expected: `time = plan2[2]`
It contains the sum of planning time and simplification time and is stored in seconds.

---

Originally posted by [nicob](https://answers.ros.org/users/85320/nicob/) with karma: 37 on 2022-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1